# We haven't done it AGAIN SINCE

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Let's say you and your siblings haven't **watched** a **film** for ages, due to your different busy working lives. And you say:

> As I remember, the last time we did it was when we were still in college, about 10 years ago, **we haven't done it again since we landed our own different jobs**, as our work schedules are hectic.

Are the bold letters correctly phrased?

- The bold letters make me a bit unsure due to the "again" before "since"...
- Also, the "our own different jobs" thing. --*grammar books* don't teach these.

Comment: There's nothing *syntactically* wrong with including ***again*** in your context. But it's totally redundant, and idiomatically "awkward", because *[haven't done it] **since*** pragmatically forces the implication that the activity *was* done at least once before the stated time. So effectively you're repeating yourself, and although redundancy is often perfectly natural in English, that's not the case here.

Comment: I guess it's better to omit that "again". Anyway, do you find "our own different jobs" awkward?

Comment: To be honest, what I find most "awkward" about your "since" clause is the ***landed our own*** bit. I can see you need *[different] **jobs***, since the broad thrust of it is that you haven't watched movies with your siblings since college - because now you have jobs, so "social synchronisation" is more difficult. But presumably you never actually worked together (on the same shift) anyway, so I'd have been happier with the more straightforward ***...we haven't done it since we got jobs...*** But this is "style advice", not really to do with "learning English" as such.

Comment: I see, got it. Maybe mine is for written.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing syntactically wrong with including "again" in your context. But it's totally redundant, and idiomatically "awkward", because "[haven't done it] since" pragmatically forces the implication that the activity was done at least once before the stated time. So effectively you're repeating yourself, and although redundancy is often perfectly natural in English, that's not the case here.

To be honest, what I find most "awkward" about your "since" clause is the "landed our own" bit. I can see you need [different] jobs, since the broad thrust of it is that you haven't watched movies with your siblings since college - because now you have jobs, so "social synchronisation" is more difficult. But presumably you never actually worked together (on the same shift) anyway, so I'd have been happier with the more straightforward ...we haven't done it since we got jobs... But this is "style advice". – FumbleFingers